# how to convert list of base64encoded image to list of file

Tags: flutter

i have saved list of images to database in blob format and retriving it as well everything works well but i want to get all the images of database and convert it to list of file. in database i am saving list of images but seperating the images with comma like this :- image1,image2 but all image are in blob format now i want to retrive that image and convert that images to file and store it to my own list but so far i am only able to convert the first image of list and not other

```
 List<File> imagesData = [];
  Future<String> getImages()async {
    imagesData.clear();
    if (savedHomeworkImages != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < savedHomeworkImages.split(",").length; i++) {
          if (savedHomeworkImages.split(",")[i].length > imagesData.length) {
            Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(savedHomeworkImages.split(",")[1]);
            String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
            File file = File("$dir/" + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + ".jpg");
            file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
            setState(() {
              imagesData.add(File(file.path));
            });
            print("This is images Data $imagesData");
            return file.path;
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

#this is how i am trying to convert blob image to file but i am not able to convert list of blob to list of file need some guidence thanks

Comment: I am assigning someone for your problem wait some time.

Comment: ok i am waiting

Answer (score 0):

> convert our Image file to bytes with the help of dart:io library.

```
   import 'dart:io' as Io;
final bytes = await Io.File(image).readAsBytes();
// or
final bytes = Io.File(image).readAsBytesSync();
```

> use dart:convert library base64Encode() function to encode bytes to Base64.
> It is the shorthand for base64.encode().

```
String base64Encode(List<int> bytes) => base64.encode(bytes);
```

Comment: i am getting error file   Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =

Comment: You need to confirm whether assets/image folder is added in pubspec.yaml.

Comment: still not working i dont know what wrong i am doing but i am not able to convert multiple base64 image to file only first index is converting

Comment: thanks for the reply but i figured it out i was returning file early that caused the error